# How to orthogonalize a non-orthogonal matrix using HLSL?

Tags: math, matrix, hlsl, ps, orthogonal

I'm just wondering whether this can be done in ps shader.I have an non-orthogonal matrix and need to orthogonalize it and using inverse-​transpose result.I turned to matlab for help,only found their instructions a bit of complicated for shaders.It might influence the performance.So is there a solution yet?Thanks for any reply:)

Comment: What is the size of your matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite complex task in the general case for an arbitrary matrix, but for a 3x3 matrix that slightly lost its orthogonality you could use the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthogonalize first two axes of your matrix and cross product to derive the third axis:

```
Xx Xy Xz
Yx Yy Yz
Zx Zy Zz

X' = X/|X|
Y' = Y"/|Y"|, Y" = Y - X'*dot(X',Y)
Z' = cross(X',Y')
```